# Avoid NSView Overuse

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I searched and thought about this a long time and couldn't find a satisfying answer:
I want to create an application with a [NSView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) in which hundreds of elements are drawn which are still interactive and should react on dragging and hovering.
Now, it seems to me, that these elements should be `NSViews`, because the `NSView` can handle all these events, but at the same time if I draw hundreds of `NSViews`, I think it is a bit of an overuse as I have read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaPerformance/Articles/CustomViews.html) (Avoid the Overuse of Views).

For comprehension let's say I want to make something like the Finder Desktop with hundreds of documents and folders on it that react to drag and hover events.

What is the right approach to this?

Comment: Screenshot? Scroll capability? Container view (table?)? Too broad a question currently

Comment: @OathComrade i think `model view controller` design pattern can help you, according to that your `NSView`'s sub class will be controlling all its children and probably can reuse those children also. Thus will reduce the number of child sub views of your main sub view.

Comment: by controlling i meant to say all the interactions as you've mentioned like hovering, dragging etc. should be done by the main `NSView`

Comment: I have found a solution by using `CALayers` instead. These are more efficient and I can draw thousands of them without a lag or freeze. But If the numbers are greater than lets say 10000, it the performance is also very bad. I considered OpenGL for this.